# SQL divide row by row with the same column by using CASE

Tags: sql, case, divide

I want to create a new column which is to calculate the percentage, I know it can use subquery to do that,

but is it possible to use CASE to do this? If using CASE how is the logic?

| Column A | Column B | Column C | New Column that i want to create |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | M0 | 72 | 72 * 100 / 72 |
| 2022-01-01 | M1 | 53 | 53 * 100 / 72 |
| 2022-01-01 | M2 | 29 | 29 * 100 / 72 |
| 2022-01-01 | M3 | 18 | 18 * 100 / 72 |
| 2022-01-01 | M4 | 2 | 2 * 100 / 72 |
| 2022-01-02 | M0 | 102 | 102 * 100 / 102 |
| 2022-01-02 | M1 | 80 | 80 * 100 / 102 |
| 2022-01-02 | M2 | 72 | 72 * 100 / 102 |
| 2022-01-02 | M0 | 32 | 32 * 100 / 102 |
| 2022-01-02 | M0 | 14 | 14 * 100 / 102 |
| ... |  |  |  |
| ... |  |  |  |
| ... |  |  |  |

Comment: How do you decide which divisor to use?

Comment: M0 is my divisor for that particular date, every date will have M0, M1, M2, M3, M4 all M1 to M4 will divide their same date M0

Comment: But 2022-01-02 has several, different M0 values.

Comment: ya so all M1-M4 from that date will divide my the same date M0

Comment: M1-M4 for 01/01/22 will divide M0 on 01/01/22
M1-M4 for 02/01/22 will divide M0 on 02/01/22
...
...
...

is this possible?

Comment: Which same MO? 2022-01-02 has the different M0 values 102, 32 and 14. How do we know which one to use as divisor?

Comment: with different M0, but will be using their own date like M1-M4 on date 1/1 use M0 on date 1/1, M1-M4 on date 2/1 use M0 on date 2/1

Comment: So the sample data you’ve provided, which has multiple M0 records for the same date, is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.colC * 100 /T2.colC
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table1 T2 
ON T1.colA = T2.colA
AND T2.ColB = 'M0'
```